# How to edit the textfield in facebook sharer.php using as3

Tags: android, facebook, actionscript-3, flash

I have made an app in as3 air for android in flash and I want to add a button that shares which level the user has reached.
I have this code for it:

```
facebook.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shareClickHandler);

function shareClickHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    var varsShare:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    varsShare.u = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ea.games.nfs13_row';
    varsShare.t = 'Try to beat me if you can';

    var urlFacebookShare:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php');
    urlFacebookShare.data = varsShare;
    urlFacebookShare.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

    navigateToURL(urlFacebookShare, 'I have made it to level 1! can you beat me?');
}
```

and I get a link to the right url but I want in the textfield something like: "I have made it to level"" Can you beat me?" or something like that does someone know how to do that?

Comment: No, you can't. Pre-populating the user message is against Facebook's platform policies.

Comment: @Li can you tell me if I can reach a same effect but with an other method?

Comment: Like I said, pre-populating the user message is against platform policies, so even if there were other methods, it would still be against policy and can get your app shut down for abuse.